# htaccess rewrite url GET parameter that doesn't have a index.php file name

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a .htaccess file in my profile directory and was able to change the url:

```
http://www.legacycloud.org/profile/index.php?user={username}
```

to

```
http://www.legacycloud.org/profile/{username}
```

and this works perflectly. But what happens if a user ignores index.php and puts:

```
http://www.legacycloud.org/profile/?user={username}
```

Normally a user wouldn't know the url parameter 'user' but just in case how would I keep make

```
http://www.legacycloud.org/profile/?user={username}
```

convert to

```
http://www.legacycloud.org/profile/{username}
```

as well.

I tried using my current code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /profile/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/profile/index\.php\?user=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [L]
#Code above works (Converts profile/index.php?user -> profile/user)

#Code below doesn't work (Needing to convert profile/?user -> profile/user)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/?user=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ ?user=$1 [L]
```

But this seems to not work. I searched around for someone to have an example but most the codes include a php file extension and when I tried to set the path to profile and just remove the file extension part, it still doesn't work.

Again, the .htaccess folder for the code above is in the profile directory, not the root.

If you need more information, comment down below.

Answer (score 0):

Your Rewrite Condition is actually matching root level requests like `/?user=foobar` but this doesn't match `/profile/?user=foobar` due to the wrong pattern. You need to write full url path in pattern of `%{THE_REQUEST}` condition, so change

```
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/?user=([a-zA-Z0- 9_-]*)\s [NC]`
```

to

```
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/profile/?\?user=([a-zA-Z0- 9_-]*)\s [NC]` .
```

Please find Final .htaccess Code below -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /profile/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/profile/index\.php\?user=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [L]
#Code above works (Converts profile/index.php?user -> profile/user)

#Code below doesn't work (Needing to convert profile/?user -> profile/user)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/profile/?\?user=([a-zA-Z0- 9_-]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0- 9 -_]+)$ ?user=$1 [L]
```